# ruby - How can I generate an array of every combination of letters and numbers of a given length?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to create a script that generates an array that lists every repeated permutation of letters and numbers (and eventually symbols) of a certain length, supplied by the user. For example:

```
User input: 4
Output:
a
b
...
zzzy
zzzz
```

I've tried a variety of ways to accomplish this, and got the effects I was looking for with nested .each loops over an array containing a-z and 0-9.

```
alphanum.each do |s|
  output << s
  alphanum.each do |t|
    output << s + t
    alphanum.each do |r|
      output << s + t + r
      alphanum.each do |i|
        output << s + t + r + i
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, this cannot be determined by an input and does not seem efficient or rubyesque to me. I tried various other combinations of loops, but none seem to work. One example:

```
# User input
puts "Max length: "
input = gets.chomp
length = input.to_i

# Iterates over the array
length.times do
  modded.each do |s|
    alphanum.each do |t|
      r = s + t
      puts r # To test output
      modded << r
    end
  end
end
```

This outputs things like `aaaaaaaaaaaaa1` and other nonsense with a length input of just 1 or 2. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This should do what you want: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination

Comment: @Rilcon42 I think that's a good method to consider, but you also have to consider that there can be repeated characters, which makes things a little bit more complicated

Comment: True, I didnt notice that he wants those. Maybe generate a combination then every possible permutation of that combination? God that would be memory intensive....

Comment: @Rilcon42 It doesn't have to be, unless you intend to store the array in-memory. The Ruby way would be to define an enumerator which emits values on demand, rather than storing them all in-memory. Ruby, in fact, already provides a function that returns this enumerator.

Comment: You said you want "every combination...", but your example suggests you want every *repeated* combination or possibly every *repeated permutaton*. (Note the two answers posted so far interpreted the question differently.) Given `a = [1,2,3]`, and a size of 2, the combinations  (after being converted to strings) are `["12", "13", "23"]`, the repeated combinations are `["11", "12", "13", "22", "23", "33"]`, the permutations are `["12", "13", "21", "23", "31", "32"]` and the repeated permutations are `["11", "12", "13", "21", "22", "23", "31", "32", "33"]`. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: I think the OP clearly wants repeated permutations, even though he wrote combinations. Look at his code : `t` doesn't depend on `s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alphanum = [*?a..?z, *?0..?9]
length.times.flat_map { |l|
  alphanum.repeated_permutation(l + 1).map(&:join)
}
```

Note that `length > 3` will give you a *lot* of results.

EDIT: As meagar says, this is very memory-intensive. An Enumerator-based answer (not as pretty, but won't kill your memory):

```
e = Enumerator.new do |y|
  length.times do |l|
    alphanum.repeated_permutation(l + 1).each do |p|
      y << p.join
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works well, but is there a way to only compute permutations of a certain length? Ex. I already have permutations of length 1-6 but need through 8, can I only get those of length 7 and 8?

Comment: @HunterRobertson: Instead of `length.times`, use `7.upto(8)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def fixed_size_repeated_combos(n)
  [*0..9, *'a'..'z'].repeated_combination(n).map(&:join)
end

def all_size_repeated_combos(n)
  (1..n).flat_map { |i| fixed_size_repeated_combos(i) }
end

all_size_repeated_combos(2)
  #=> ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d",
  #    "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
  #    "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04",
  #    "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "0a", "0b", "0c", "0d", "0e", "0f",
  #    ...
  #    "28", "29", "2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "2e", "2f", "2g", "2h", "2i",
  #    ...
  #    "ww", "wx", "wy", "wz", "xx", "xy", "xz", "yy", "yz", "zz"] 

all_size_repeated_combos(1).size #=> 36 
all_size_repeated_combos(2).size #=> 702 
all_size_repeated_combos(3).size #=> 9138 
all_size_repeated_combos(4).size #=> 91389 
all_size_repeated_combos(5).size #=> 749397
```

See [Array#repeated_combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination).

For "permuations", rather than "combinations", find and replace "combos" with "permbos" and "combination" with "permutation".

Comment: The math doesn't seem to add up here. The size of each set should be `36^n`. It seems your solution is doing something funny and omitting some results that (at least in my reading of the question) should be included. For example, after `1z`, your solution loops to `22`, and the strings  `20` and `21` are missing. After `gg`, your solution jumps straight to `hh`, and the strings `h0..hg` are missing.

Comment: Sorry, `36^n` assums you only want results with a length of `n`. The correct set size should be (36^n) + (36^(n-1)) + (36^(n-2)) + ... + 36, which is still many more results than you're outputting. The correct number of terms for `N = 5` would be 62,193,780, not 749,397.

Comment: @meagar, you'll calculations are for permutations and repeated permutations. You'll see I'm computing repeated combinations. See my comment on the question.

Comment: You're right, I assumed permutations are what they're after.